# How can I use `over` from Control.Lens but perform a monadic action and collect the results?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

The problem is pretty simple. I have a structure that looks something like this

```
data Foo = Foo [Bar]
data Bar = Boo | Moo Item Int
data Item = Item String Int
```

and I have a lens for changing the contents of the `Item`s inside the data structure, such as this

```
let foos = [Foo [Boo, Moo (Item "bar" 20) 10]]
over (traverse._Foo._Moo._1._Item._1) ("foo" ++) foos

-- which yields [Foo [Boo, Moo (Item "foobar" 20) 10]]
```

The structure here isn't important, I just wanted to show an example that uses prisms and something deeply nested.

Now the problem is that I need the function passed to `over` to be `String -> IO String`, instead of just `String -> String`. A similar thing to what I'm looking for here is something like `mapM`, but with lenses. Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lens provides the [`traverseOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.2/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v%3atraverseOf) function, which is exactly like `mapM` but takes a lens-like (it takes a traversal, which includes lenses and prims) over which you want to `map`.

```
traverseOf :: Functor f => Iso s t a b       -> (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
traverseOf :: Functor f => Lens s t a b      -> (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
traverseOf :: Applicative f => Traversal s t a b -> (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

So for your example, you can just use:

```
traverseOf (traverse._Foo._Moo._1._Item._1) (... expression of type String -> IO String ...) foos
```

There is also an operator version of `traverseOf`, called `%%~`.

---

If you're a bit familar with the representation of lenses inside the lens library, you might notice that `traverseOf = id`! So, with this knowledge, you can rewrite the example to just:

```
(traverse._Foo._Moo._1._Item._1) (... expression of type String -> IO String ...) foos
```

(You even used `traverse` which is just `mapM` to build the traversal! lenses / prims are just like `traverse`, but more specific.)

But this is just an aside, you might nevertheless want to use `traverseOf` for clarity.